# How to get rid of blank spaces around an ImageView inside a CardView

Tags: android, imageview, cardview

Below screenshot, I am inserting an image, using `ImageView`, into a `CardView`.

The problem is, I seem can't get rid of the empty space below the Image. (highlighted by light blue)

I tried [a solution that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyNMY.jpg), but it requires me to explicitly specify the image height, which I try not to, because, the source can be various, and I need the image to flexibly scale up/down (with same aspect ratio) depending on the card width.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

And here's the code snippet:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="7dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caption_text"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:layout_below="@id/caption_text"
            android:src="@drawable/food"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**So, is there any way to make the `CardView` automatically wrap around the image, (without leaving any empty space) and without specifying the image height explicitly?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `<RelativeLayout>` height to `wrap_content`. Currently, it has a circular dependency in height.

**[EDIT]**

We need to set the property `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for the image to scale with the source. Its `false` by default!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="7dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caption_text"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/caption_text"
            android:src="@drawable/food"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: tried it but your solution doesn't work. btw i changed the screenshot, because the earlier shows wrong light-blue highlight.

Comment: silly android duh. how can they make some weird config as default anyway. :/

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the scaleType to `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`, or some other scaleType.
See here:
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: this is a wonderful alternative as well. thank you for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

I am using **RoundedImageView** plugin

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
....
....
android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

This worked for me.